# Issues with creating a constructor for square matrices

Tags: c++, class, matrix, constructor

I'm creating a square-matrix class for a simple university project. I'm having an issue with the constructor (not the default one). As I need only square matrices, I wrote it like

```
      sqmatrix(int R): rank(R)
  {
            std::vector < std::vector <double> > MATRIX; 
             MATRIX.resize(rank);           
  }
```

There may be or may not be other issues (I'm a beginner) but the most important one I'd like an answer for is: suppose I create a sqmatrix A; in main(), how can I fill it? I'm not sure how do I access the data (and write) inside the vector of vector.

Even if I don't use vector but create an array of pointers... how do I fill them when the only member is R?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If that's a constructor, why is your class name not capitalized? Everything allocated statically inside the constructor (`MATRIX`) will get deleted as soon as the method exists. You don't. You only allocate space.

Comment: I honestly think you should start with some entry level c++ tutorial that focuses on it's object oriented nature. You seem to be lacking in most basic concepts for the starters, you don't know basic c++ types, ending with quite quite peculiar coding style... naming variable with all caps and classes all lower is quite uncommon. My concern is that you probably won't be able to understand the answers with your current knowledge.

Comment: @Alexandru That's a bizarre rule that class names must be capitalized. Seems the C++ standards committee didn't get that memo.

Comment: @Praetorian well, this doesn't have to do anything with C++, it's common to most (if not all) programming languages that are OOP, and I doubt someone will tell you "thank you" for not sticking to those standards.

Comment: @Alexandru So what does that make the C++ standard library? Uncommon or non-standard? Or maybe it's *not OOP*? Also, at first I didn't read past the first sentence of your first comment. But now that I have, the rest is even more nonsensical than the first sentence!

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie Maybe you're confusing _standard_ with coding conventions, where in fact some exist that advise using camel cased class names.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ true, the word *standard* is in wrong context in my comment, it should be replaced with *convention*.

Comment: @Praetorian, as mentioned above, I was wrong using the word *standard*, hence the confusion of the sentence, capitalizing class names is a convention.

Comment: @Alexandru That's better, but it's still not enough of a widely followed convention, at least in the C++ world, that you can authoritatively state it should be adhered to. Boost is an example of a popular, highly regarded set of libraries that doesn't follow your naming convention.

Comment: @Praetorian I see your point, and I don't want to get into the details why boost does it, as I really do not know, but for the ease of other fellow programmers to read your code, I consider one should get used to this convention, unless there is a serious reason why it should be avoided, especially when it comes to the point where such things as indentation and "good" namings are yet not a habit.

Answer (score 2):

`MATRIX.resize(rank);` will result in `MATRIX` containing `rank` number of `std::vector<double>`s, but each of those vectors will be empty. Use this instead:

```
sqmatrix(int R): rank(R)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> MATRIX; 
    MATRIX.resize(rank, std::vector<double>(rank));           
}
```

But your code seems odd. You're creating a local variable named `MATRIX` within the constructor. Shouldn't it be a data member of the `sqmatrix` class? If it is, then you should use the constructor initializer list to initialize it

```
sqmatrix(int R)
: rank(R)
, MATRIX(R, std::vector<double>(R))
{
}
```

To access the elements of the matrix, use `std::vector::operator[]`

```
double elem = MATRIX[r][c];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code creates a local variable `MATRIX` there is no way to access this variable outside this function. Perhaps you want to create a class variable:

```
public:
    std::vector < std::vector <double> > MATRIX;
```

Now you can access it outside the class.

You can fill like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < classinstance.MATRIX.size(); ++i)
    for(int p = 0; p < classinstance.MATRIX[i].size(); ++p)
        classinstance.MATRIX[i][p] = /* data */;
```

You can also use algorithms like `std::fill` to fill your matrix.